# use text in cell as check box caption

Tags: excel, checkbox, vba

I'm trying to alter this line of code, `.Caption = .Range("Key6!B" & myCell.Row & "").Value`, in the below macro to display the corresponding value on key6 as the check box caption. None of my alterations seem to be working.

```
With ActiveSheet
        For Each myCell In .Range(cellRange).Cells
            With myCell
                Set myBox = .Parent.CheckBoxes.Add(Top:=.Top, Width:=.Width, Left:=.Left, Height:=.Height)

                With myBox
                    .LinkedCell = linkedColumn & myCell.Row
                    .Caption = .Range("Key6!B" & myCell.Row & "").Value
                    .Name = "checkbox_" & myCell.Address(0, 0)
                End With

                .NumberFormat = ";;;"
            End With

        Next myCell
    End With
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: You shouldn't need the double quotes but that shouldn't make a difference.  .Caption = .Range("Key6!B" & myCell.Row).Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.Caption = WorkSheets("Key6").Range("B" & myCell.Row & "").Value
```